# How do I count occurrence of a text within a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

*The question seems too straight forward that it can be answered by a simple google search (**OR A SIMPLE FORMULA**), but I neither found a single question nor a doc explaining this.*

The cells in question contains multiple URLs separated by new line (enter key). Note, the below values are in a single cell.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs
```

I'm trying to find a forumla that says how many "https" are there in each cell of a column. I tried `COUNTIF` and `COUNTA` but its not giving the correct answer.

Comment: Looks like `=COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,CHAR(10))))` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below formula:

```
=Countif(Transpose(SPLIT(Trim(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"//\S+","")),":")),"*")
```

> Change cell reference per your need.

Comment: Thanks for answering. May i know where the 'newline' command is given here?